# Pulling information from API and adding it to database (MEAN stack)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I feel like a complete moron but me and a friend are working on a project together and having trouble getting the first route to return the items requested from the Etsy API and have getAllListings add the items to the database. If you can see something glaringly obvious that we are doing wrong please let me know.

I should also mention that while the statement `console.dir(body)` does print out the items to the terminal it does not look like the contents are being passed to `GET '/api/etsy/getListings'`

Thanks!

routes.js

```
//this i want to return a list of active listings from the users shop.

app.get('/api/etsy/getListings',function(req, res){
    bEtsy.getAllListings(req, res, function(err, body) {
    });
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

bEtsy.js

```
var standardCallback = function (err, status, body, headers, callback) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return callback(err, null);
  }

  if (body) {
    console.dir(body);
    return callback(null, body);  // this gives me an error
  }
} 


var getAllListings = function(itemId, callback){
  var Item = mongoose.model('Item');
  var listingsParams = {
    include_private: true
  }

  etsy.auth().get(
    '/shops/'+etsy.shop+'/listings/active', 
    listingsParams, 
    function(err, status, body, headers){
      var newi = new Item({name: body.title, stock: body.count, owner: "00000000000000000000", 
        etsy:{listingId: body.listing_id, stock: body.count}});
      newi.save(function(err){
        if (err) return handError(err);
      });
      standardCallback(err, status, body, headers, callback);
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling this function with three parameters, when it only takes two

```
bEtsy.getAllListings(req, res, function(err, body) {
});
```

On top of that the first argument `itemId` is being passed the request object and then it is also never used inside the function itself but some global variable called `listingsParams` is?!?